# Align elements CSS

Tags: html, css

Not all of my text is aligning the way I want it to the second line that I want to align in at the bottom of the image still but I want it to be on the next line beneath the first. I am new to all of this CSS stuff and this project is for my history class so help is very appreciated as always!

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Biography</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <a href = home.html>Home</a>
    <a href = bio.html>Biography</a>
    <a href = campaign.html>Campaign</a>
    <a href = pp.html>Political Platform</a>
    <body>
    <p>
        <img src= images/william.jpg/ height = 300 width = 300>
        Sir William Higgins was born on 02/02/1987. He was top of his class at Horn E.U.He was the number one draft choice for the MLB in 2000 and has won every golden globe award ever.
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code on my CSS stylesheet:

```
img {
    border: solid 2px black;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: curier;
}

p {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Move your links inside the body tag and put quotes around attribute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. The `<a>` tags must be in the `<body>` tag.
2. The `<img>` tag must be outside of the `<p>`.
3. To separate the links and the image, I put in a `<br>`.
4. All attributes must *MUST* be in double quotes. For example, on the `href` attribute, the URL must be in quotes.

**[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/PUt7B/3/)**

Here is what the HTML should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Biography</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="bio.html">Biography</a>
    <a href="campaign.html">Campaign</a>
    <a href="pp.html">Political Platform</a>

    <br>

    <img src="images/william.jpg/" height="300" width="300">
    <p>Sir William Higgins was born on 02/02/1987. He was top of his class at Horn E.U.He was the number one draft choice for the MLB in 2000 and has won every golden globe award ever.</p>
</body>
```

Your CSS is fine.

If you also want your links to be on top of each other, add a `<br>` after each `</a>`.

**EDIT:** To make the links appear on top of one another, it would be better if you put the links into a [`<nav>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) like this:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="bio.html">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="campaign.html">Campaign</a></li>
    <li><a href="pp.html">Political Platform</a></li>
</nav>
```

and then style them using this CSS:

```
nav li {
    display: block;
}

nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle with `nav` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/27kew/5/).**

Answer (score -1):

As said your markup is not valid.

If you want your links under each other, just insert a `<br>` after each link

Comment: Generally, better to avoid <br /> tags, as it muddies up the html, and makes it a pain to maintain. Reserve BR tags for formatting paragraph text etc. Move the links inside the <body> as others have said, and if you want them each on their own line you can do this with CSS "Display: block" or better yet put them in an unordered list "<ul>".

Comment: Mitchell: using display block just creates another problem. You get big blocks of anchors. And why is ul better than breaks. It is still a change to the markup

Comment: Displaying navigation in a list is better than breaks for a number of reasons. Lets say you wanted to add a 5px right margin to all the links, how would you do that with breaks? You could apply it to the anchors but what happens when you have another link? Having them all in a list means styles can be applied directly to all of them the same, and evenly. <br /> is meant for use in formatting blocks of text, not html layout.

Comment: I know. But where does it say that it is a menu